# Grails with MongoDB not saving null value

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

This is a customer domain class in Grails(v3.1):

```
class Customer {

   static mapWith = 'mongo'

   String id
   String email
   Boolean blacklisted
   String name
   String telephone

   Date dateCreated
   Date lastUpdated

   String language = 'en'

   static constraints = {
       email nullable: false
       blacklisted nullable: false
       name nullable: true
       language nullable: true
       telephone nullable: true
   }

   static mapping = {
       version false
   }
}
```

I can insert and update into the Customer collection in MongoDB using this class, and it is working fine. The issue occurs when I try to save one of the fields with null value.

```
customer.telephone = null
customer.save()
```

Setting a value to null has no effect in the field in MongoDB collection, its value will remain set to the value before the update. For example, if the telephone is set to "1234567" and when I update it to null, the value in MongoDB remains "1234567".

I have tried using `failOnError: true` and `flush: true` in `save()`, both are not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is lastUpdated updated after saving with a null value? Are other, non-null values updated in the same commit as the null value?

Comment: @MikeW, lastUpdated field is updating after saving with null value. And non-null values are updated in the same commit as the null value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the mongo driver directly to see if it is a mongo issue or a Gorm issue.

```
Customer.collection.updateOne([_id:'the-id'],[telephone:null])
```